# Do ffmpeg-python and ffmpy are system version independent?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, ffmpy

I am making a python-based software that actually uses my Window's ffmpeg version. But I am thinking about to make it crossplatform, so, I heard that [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) uses ffmpeg, so I want to know what is the module that it uses. But also, searching I found these two ffmpeg python modules.

In other words, three questions:

1. Does [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) is system version independent?
2. Does [ffmpy](https://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is system version independent?
3. What ffmpeg module does [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) uses?

Comment: `youtube-dl` uses [its own wrapper](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/postprocessor/ffmpeg.py) around the native binary

Comment: @MTCoster oh then I was wrong. So I am looking for a ffmpeg module

Comment: Why not try it yourself? Write a quick test script for each package then run it on Windows and *nix

Comment: @MTCoster because I hace ffmpeg installed and configured on my computer (windows) If it is dependent I won’t know. Can you help me out checking it ?

Comment: Then spin up a VM/uninstall it temporarily/use another computer

Comment: @MTCoster I am going to try a VM! Thanks for the idea. If you have more, they will be welcome.